# Force version 2 of ARKit with deployment target iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, arkit

I have an app using ARKit 2 functionalities.

- With a deployment target set on iOS11 the camera is working on iOS11 devices but freeze on iOS12
- With a deployment target set on iOS12 the camera is working on iOS12 devices, but the app can't run on iOS11 devices.

Is there a way to target iOS11 while forcing the use of ARKit2, so I could still run the app on iOS11 devices while blocking the functionality for iOS11 users ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Swift Availability Attributes.

```swift
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
  //activate your ARKit2 functionalities here
} else {
  //fallback for iOS 11 or lower
}
```